# MatLab find all pixels value

Tags: matlab, max, pixel

I have DailyET.tif map and I want to find max pixel value and pixel location (x,y)....

When I try it

a=imread('DailyET.tif');

than I open "A" at workspace I see pixel value but not have all pixels.(only have 7251*8091 single value)

how can I open image with all pixel information???

Comment: Try to highlight your code and to describe more in details what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=imread('DailyET.tif');

% Displaying your image
figure,
imshow(a)

% Maximum value in a
[MAX_VALUE Location] = max(max(a));
```